# How can I add if statement to a deleteview? CBV django

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

Hey I want to add if statement and according to it decide if to delete the object or not.
I could not find it online.
In general how can I add if statements to any CBV including Update for example..

This is my DeleteView func:

```
class PostDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Post
    success_url = reverse_lazy('TheApp:post_list')
```

EDIT! THE SOLUTION THAT WORKED FOR ME:(Thanks to AKX)

```
def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if (Post.author == request.user.username):
            return super().delete(request, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return HttpResponse('You are not the owner of this Post! You can not delete it!')
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, as you know, CBVs' methods map to HTTP methods, so just override `delete()` and add your condition:

```
class SomeView(..., DeleteView, ...):
    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.GET.get('really') != 'true':
            return HttpResponse('I knew you were just kidding!')
        return super().delete(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: So I can override any cbv just using List, Update etc. ?

Comment: "list" and "update" are not a thing for CBVs -- they are for Django Rest Framework views.

Comment: I meant that I can override UpdateView by def update(....) like you did with delete

Comment: UpdateView uses `def post()`... follow the class hierarchy up from https://github.com/django/django/blob/75410228dfd16e49eb3c0ea30b59b4c0d2ea6b03/django/views/generic/edit.py#L197

Comment: Thank you bro.. appreciate it